# How to make an executable with cx_freeze?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I making an executable with python 2.6. I made the setup code.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "Aimball",
    version = "2.6",
    description = "Aimball Game",
    executables = [Executable("aimball.py", base = base)])
```

Then what do I do? I have read the cx_freeze documentation and other answers but not sure what they exactly mean. Could someone explain it clearer as I just started programming in Python a few weeks ago. Just in case I'm running Windows 7 and version 4.3.1 of cx_freeze with Python 2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save that file in the same folder as your `aimball.py` script, as something like `setup.py`. Then open up a command prompt in that directory (you can use the `cd` command to Change Directory). Then run `python setup.py build`. If it works, it should create a `build/exe...` folder containing your executable and some other files it needs to run.

Comment: Don't worry - I'm not that concerned about my reputation score ;-)